# Question about centering a Div 

Tags: css

```
div
{
margin:90px auto;
}
```

This code centers the div in chrome with a top margin of 90px, but the results are different in all other browsers ..

is there a common method to center the div and have a top margin at the same time ?

Comment: Actually that would set the top *and* bottom margins to 90px, then the left and right margins to automatic.

Comment: Yes but it centers the div only in chrome ..

Comment: Unless there is another CSS rule governing the width of your div, the div will be essentially 100% width.  As N. Lucas answer eludes to, you must set a width for the div (less that its container) for it to be centred.  If you just wanted the contents of the div to be centred then  Salil's answer is what you want

Comment: i have set the width to 700px which is less than the body's width .. but still it works in chrome alone..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
div {
    margin: 90px auto;
    width: 900px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

This works for me in Firefox. I get a 900px by 100px box centered with a 90px top and bottom margin.

Comment: it worked.. actually i tagged the div inside a section tag.. which seems to be supported only by chrome..

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want the text content of the div to be aligned centred if so use.

```
div
{
  margin:90px auto;
  text-align:centre;
}
```

Comment: It'd be 'center', anyways, not 'centre'.  Just the messenger. :p